# Residue of complex exponential

Tags: residue-calculus, laurent-series

I need to find the residue of $e^{\frac 1{1-z}}$ using Laurent series. How would I manipulate the function to make it easier? I need to find all singularities and the corresponding residues. I believe the only residue is at z=1

Comment: You know the series $e^w = 1+w+\dots$, right? Plug $w=1/(1-z)$.

Comment: To find the residue, I need the term that contains 1/z. I don't think this series will have one, right?

Comment: Is that a better question?

Comment: It is better now. But you are mistaken about z=0. The function is holomorphic there.

Comment: So are there any singularities?

Comment: $e^{\frac{1}{1-0}} = e^1 = e$. The exponential function is meromorphic (holomorphic in the whole plane) and it has an essential singularity in $\infty$.

Comment: Oh I just realized I made a mistake in my question. The singularity is at z=1

Comment: To show it's essential construct two sequences that converge to $1$ and for which your function takes different values. My answer here may be useful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1201669/type-of-singularity-of-a-complex-function/1201704#1201704